# Popular DataGridView com Entity Framwork

Tags: c#, sql, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

1. Possuo no SQL Server um banco de dados chamado LOJA;
2. Nesse banco possuo uma tabela chamada Funcionario, ela contém 5 colunas sendo elas respectivamente: Nome, CPF, DataAdmissao, DataDemissao, IdFuncionario.
3. Na minha aplicação C# eu já fiz a conexão com o banco de dados por meio do ADO.NET Model Entity Framwork e o modelo se chama LojaEntities.
4. Quero agora popular o datagridview1 com somente 3 colunas da tabela Funcionario, que seriam respectivamente; IDFuncionario, Nome, CPF.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer a povoação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enfim, pesquisei um pouco mais e acho que cheguei a solução. O que soluciona meu problema é o chamado objeto anônimo, onde precisamos selecionar mais de um item de u

```
var db = new LojaEntities();
var consulta = from p in db.Funcionarios select new {p.Nome, p.CPF, p.Endereco};
datagridview1.DataSource = consulta.ToList();
```